# lightning-formatted-date-time - showing previous date (LWC)

Tags: web, components, salesforce-lightning

I am using the tag "lightning-formatted-date-time" in my lightning web components with the value "2019-06-02" but it is displaying the previous date.

I am not getting if the value is not a valid one for the tag. Please suggest.

Here is the playground code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/nLT72mjyV/1/edit

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When i run the same playground code, i get displayed the "Jun 02, 2019" date. 
It might be a timezone thing. I would check your OS timezone settings. Also i would try to add the attribute `time-zone="UTC"` to it, to ensure correct formatting.

Also try to read through the documentation you can find here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation

Answer (score 0):

This is because of current user time zone. Salesforce save datetime in UTC formate and while returning it give in current user time zone formate.